# codeigniter auto post to twitter using latest twitter api

Tags: api, codeigniter, twitter

I want to post/tweet to my twitter account using my website developed using codeigniter(version 1.7) framework.

How to integrate the latest twitter api to codeigniter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://www.haughin.com/code/twitter/ or alternately take a look at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Filename: libraries/tweet.php

Line Number: 574


I'm getting this error when I use 'statuses/update_with_media'

sample code:

$this->tweet->call('post', 'statuses/update_with_media', array('status' => 'test message', 'media' => array('media_url' => 'http://www.infobarrel.com/media/image/15674.png')));


How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Below code is worl for me I wrote in core PHP

```
$this->settings  = array(
    'oauth_access_token'        => "****************",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "****************",
    'consumer_key'              => "****************",
    'consumer_secret'           => "****************",
);

$twitter       = new TwitterAPIExchange($this->settings);
$url           = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json';
$requestMethod = 'POST';
$postfields    = array('status' => $message);
$res           = $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->setPostfields($postfields)
    ->performRequest();
```

Refer this url: http://github.com/j7mbo/twitter-api-php